# Beaglebone: gcc include path error while trying to build using 'make'

Tags: gcc, makefile, cmusphinx, angstrom-linux, beagleboneblack

I am trying to build cmu pocketsphinx on my beaglebone black for speech recognition. I have downloaded the source code for sphinxbase and ran ./configure. Now, when I run 'make' I get the following errors:

```
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/root/Pocketsphinx/sphinxbase-0.8/src'
Making all in libsphinxbase
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/root/Pocketsphinx/sphinxbase-0.8/src/libsphinxbase'
Making all in util
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/root/Pocketsphinx/sphinxbase-0.8/src/libsphinxbase/util'
/bin/sh ../../../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -std=gnu99 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../include -I../../../include/sphinxbase -I../../../include -I../../../include   -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7  -g -O2 -Wall -MT bitvec.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/bitvec.Tpo -c -o bitvec.lo bitvec.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -std=gnu99 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../include -I../../../include/sphinxbase -I../../../include -I../../../include "-I/usr/include/python2.7" -I/usr/include/python2.7 -g -O2 -Wall -MT bitvec.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/bitvec.Tpo -c bitvec.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/bitvec.o

gcc: error: -I/usr/include/python2.7: No such file or directory

make[3]: *** [bitvec.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/root/Pocketsphinx/sphinxbase-0.8/src/libsphinxbase/util'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/root/Pocketsphinx/sphinxbase-0.8/src/libsphinxbase'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/root/Pocketsphinx/sphinxbase-0.8/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I have checked under /usr/include and I can see python2.7 folder there. But, in the above it says that gcc can not find the python2.7 directory. I am kind of lost. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

GCC is interpreting that argument as the name of a file to be compiled, not a `-I` option.  I find it exceedingly odd that it's putting quotes around one of the arguments.  My suspicion is that this is because one of the characters in that argument is not a standard ASCII character.  For example maybe you've used a different dash character (not ASCII code 45 / hex 0x2d, but instead some other character code that shows up sort of like a dash).

Comment: Ya, now that you mentioned it I can see that too. But, I haven't modified anything in the makefile. I just downloaded the source code for the sphinxbase from their site and followed their tutorial for installing it.

Comment: Check SVN trunk, your version seems to be outdated.

Comment: Do you mean pocketsphinx version or the gcc? The former I downloaded from pocketsphinx official website, which is the latest version they have.