# Beaglebone black and pocketsphinx gcc error

Tags: python, gcc

I'm having a problem compiling pocketsphinx-0.8 on my beaglebone black. I have seen [Beaglebone: gcc include path error while trying to build using 'make'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822422/beaglebone-gcc-include-path-error-while-trying-to-build-using-make) and I am having the same output upon typing 'make'.

It seems like this is a problem with gcc not recognizing some characters in '-I/usr/include/python2.7' because the /usr/include/python2.7 directory exists.

I'm compiling this on my beaglebone black running angstrom.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have exactly the same symptoms as in the linked posting? If so, make sure that you don't have any unexpected characters in the build files, like e.g. MS Windows EOL characters. If in doubt, check a hexdump. Also, reduce the offending code to a minimal example, which makes it easier to find the actual error.

Comment: Thanks - and yes my error is identical as the linked error.

I checked for unexpected characters, but the error happened with a clean pull/build from pocketsphinx source repo. It seems to be the problem that '-I/usr/include/python2.7 ' is in quotes in the printed error.